# Solar radiation modelling on vertical surfaces

Tags: solar-radiation

Are there any methods to measure solar radiation on vertical building facades using Esri's Solar Analyst?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As someone new to our site it may help to take the 2 minute [Tour] to see how it works.  There is also some advice available on [How to frame a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) that I would like to recommend to you.  When you say "Esri's Solar Analyst" do you mean the [Solar Radiation tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000t4000000) from the Spatial Analyst extension?  For this question I think knowing the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using will be important.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. There are methods to derive irradiation of facades using raster 2.5D data but they are not out there yet. We plan to release such a tool as a QGIS plugin soon. You can keep a lookout for SEBE, Solar Energy on Building Envelopes.